# Test regularity of Simplex

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, simplex

A simplex is regular if its all edges have the same length.

How to test in Mathematica whether a `Simplex` is regular or not, without checking all the edges manually? I'm not really familiar with loops in Mathematica. I also can't find in the documentation how to access the vertices of a `Simplex`.

Comment: Does `(Equal @@ EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & @@ Simplex[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]` count as "checking all the edges manually"?

Comment: @J.M. No, it is okay, I can make a function from this. If you repost it as an answer, I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use `Subsets[]` to enumerate the edges of your simplex:

```
regularSimplexQ[Simplex[vertices_]] := 
       MatrixQ[vertices] && Subtract @@ Dimensions[vertices] == 1 && 
       Equal @@ EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[vertices, {2}];
regularSimplexQ[_] := False
```

Try it out:

```
regularSimplexQ[Simplex[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]]
   False

regularSimplexQ[Simplex[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]]
   True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[regSimplexQ]
regSimplexQ = Equal @@ PropertyValue[{MeshRegion[#, Simplex[{1, 2, 3, 4}]] & @@ #, 1}, 
 MeshCellMeasure] &;

regSimplexQ@Simplex[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

> True

```
regSimplexQ@Simplex[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

> False